# Existence of a matrix with some following properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exists a matrix $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ $A=$\begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b\\
 c & d\\
   \end{bmatrix}
be a $2×2$  matrix with real entries  With $A^2=A\neq 0$ such that $|a|+|b|<1 , |c|+|d|<1$ ?
I think we have to use triangle inequality to do that .
But unable to solve.

Comment: Are you familiar with any matrix norms, or more specifically, operator norms?

Comment: I know norms of linear operators on banach space . Do you want to mean Operator norm of a matrix is the norm corresponding to the linear translation of the matrix.

Comment: There is no such matrix (real or even complex). You can just compute $A^2$, and set the equality conditions as $a^2 + bc = a$ , $d^2 + bc = d$, $b(a+d) = b$ and $c(a+d) = c$. From the first two conditions you get $a = d \lor (a + d) = 1$, do a case analysis and eliminate all possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I think we're on the same page. I was hoping for a more positive response, because there's an elegant proof if you know a nice formula for the operator norm with respect to the $\infty$-norm on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e. $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|_\infty \le 1} \|Ax\|_\infty$). But, perhaps you're just supposed to get your hands dirty, and muck around with $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: @Anon as $A\ne 0$ minimal polynomial of A will be $x(x-1)$ that means the eigen values are 0 and 1. So trace a+d=1 that I know.

Comment: @Spectrum nice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $A²=A$, $tr(A)=1$ and $det(A)=0$.

So, $a + d = 1$ and $ad = bc$.

If $|b| < 1 - |a|$ and $|c| < 1 - |d|$,
hence, $|bc| < 1 - |a| - |d| + |ad|$
or, $|a| + |d| < 1 = |a + d|$ (contradiction)